# WordPress vertical menu hover effect positioning

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hoping someone might be able to help me as I'm currently pulling my hair out. I've got a vertical menu in WordPress and am trying to styling to the active and hover. I've got the effect working but it's in the wrong place.

Here's the menu:

```
<nav class="vertical-header-menu-container"><ul id="main-menu" class="d-none d-md-block navbar-nav vertical-header-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item menu-item-1106 "><a title="Home" href="https://and-it.co.uk/dan/" class="nav-link"><div class="title-content">Home</div></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-636 current_page_item nav-item menu-item-1073 active "><a title="Blog" href="https://and-it.co.uk/dan/blog/" class="nav-link"><div class="title-content">Blog</div></a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

And here is the CSS applied:

```
#main-menu .current-menu-item a::before,
#main-menu .current_page_item a::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
#main-menu li a::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 100%;
background: #15bf86;
height: 3px;
-webkit-transition-property: right;
transition-property: right;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#main-menu li a:hover {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
#main-menu li a:hover:before {
right: 0;
}
#main-menu li li a:before {
bottom: 10%;
}
```

The idea is that a solid line appears below the active menu item or below the item being hovered over. It's currently above the items.

I thought I was probably using the wrong selectors but have tried changing them and no joy. I also thought that maybe I should be using 'after' instead of 'before' but again, no joy.

Would appreciate any help or direction you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, this is what you expected

```css
#main-menu li a::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 100%;
background: #15bf86;
height: 3px;
-webkit-transition-property: right;
transition-property: right;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#main-menu li a:hover {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
#main-menu li a:hover:after {
right: 0;
}
#main-menu li li a:after {
bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="vertical-header-menu-container"><ul id="main-menu" class="d-none d-md-block navbar-nav vertical-header-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item menu-item-1106 "><a title="Home" href="https://and-it.co.uk/dan/" class="nav-link"><div class="title-content">Home</div></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-636 current_page_item nav-item menu-item-1073 active "><a title="Blog" href="https://and-it.co.uk/dan/blog/" class="nav-link"><div class="title-content">Blog</div></a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet and it works exactly as I expected. Using your CSS on my actual site however results in the same thing my code did... the lines appear above the menu item instead of below. My guess now is that this is conflicting with something else on the site perhaps?

Comment: So that, if it's possible to give the site link..which i'll try to figure it out.